# Ubuntu won't install on a Mac Mini G4 due to an error trying to install the `linux-powerpc-smp` kernel

Tags: 12.04, installation, powerpc, mac-mini

Trying to install the Alternate Install 12.04 [ubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc (MD5 c57149dc4f31372912aab2856c08107b).iso] on a Mac Mini G4 meant to be a home server, I am getting this error message:

```
An error was returned while trying to install the kernel into the target system.
Kernel package: 'linux-powerpc-smp'
Check /var/log/syslog or see virtual console 4 for details.
```

The only options I choose are:

- Set user name "Tino Sino", username "tino"
- Encrypt home: Yes (tried with No too)
- Partition disks: Guided - use entire disk (created #3 as ext4, #4 as swap)

The CD MD5 is the right one.

Comment: I have had the same issue on powerPCs. specifically on a Mac server. I found no real answer, and just sold the servers. I found that ubuntu server 8.04 worked though. did an in place upgrade to 9.04 and it crashed again. G4s just aren't fun to work with.good luck!

Comment: What does virtual console 4 have to say?  Sometimes it will be more explicit about what happened.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).